# 32feet.net library not working in wince

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-ce, 32feet

using 32feet library to develope bluetooth application for a device runnig `WINCE 6.0`. This library is not working in WINCE 6.0 .
I am using VS 2005 to develope application. No error in compilation. but the application is not working in device.

The device's supports only chinese language.
It shows error  in chinese with just the following part in english.

```
"InTheHand.Net.Personal, version=3.5.605.0  public key token EA38CAA273134499"
```

Need help to figure out what might be the issue.

Comment: I don't think that is enough information to get a proper answer. Are you able to try on another device or a VM?

Comment: The application developed with the same library and api's runs in my laptop(window 8), it works fine and i tried running it in a  wince simulator, obviously simulator do not support bluetooth, so it showed an error that bluetooth stack is not available.

Comment: I hope someone can help you. Sorry mate!

Comment: Can you post the Chinese error text? Perhaps somebody can translate it to English.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have Bluetooth stack available on your WinCE device. Some vendors do provide it with the CAB installer.

Also check if the Btdrt.DLL is present in windows directory of your device. It is a runtime DLL that provides a sample management API to the user program.